# Easy way to conditionally create fields an object?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an app that relies heavily on data input and so I have to construct different kinds of objects with required and non-required data, and the non-required data piece is my issue here, as this leads to a lot of additional code and I am wondering if there is a way to avoid this.

Here I have a form that has 6 fields (its just one example, but I have the same case in many other places in the app), 2 of them are required, the rest are not, and I wrote this function to handle the object creation:

```
  const handleAddSupplier = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = e.target.elements;

    const supplierData = {
      name: formData.name.value,
      companyId: formData.companyId.value,
      ...((formData.country.value || formData.city.value || formData.postalCode.value || formData.street.value) && {
        address: {
          ...(formData.country.value && { country: formData.country.value }),
          ...(formData.city.value && { city: formData.city.value }),
          ...(formData.postalCode.value && { postalCode: formData.postalCode.value }),
          ...(formData.street.value && { street: formData.street.value }),
        },
      }),
    };

    console.log(supplierData);
  };
```

And it works, but its too much code in my opinion, I suspect that there is an easier way to do this.

The "signature" of the object that must be created is:

```
{
  name: "",
  companyId: "",
  address: {
    country: "",
    city: "",
    postalCode: "",
    street: ""
  }
}
```

The address object and its fields are entirely optional, so if none of the fields of address is available (i.e. the user inputs only the required fields and nothing else), the address object should not be created at all, not even as an empty object.

My code works, I am just interested to see if there are other simpler ways.

Edit: I destructured the object a bit and saved myself some writing, but still, what if I have 10 non-required fields, do I conditionally "OR" them all 10?

```
const { name, companyId, country, city, postalCode, street } = e.target.elements;

const supplierData = {
  name: name.value,
  companyId: companyId.value,
  ...((country.value || city.value || postalCode.value || street.value) && {
    address: {
      ...(country.value && { country: country.value }),
      ...(city.value && { city: city.value }),
      ...(postalCode.value && { postalCode: postalCode.value }),
      ...(street.value && { street: street.value }),
    },
  }),
};
```

Or another way of writing the same thing:

```
const {
  name: { value: name },
  companyId: { value: companyId },
  country: { value: country },
  city: { value: city },
  postalCode: { value: postalCode },
  street: { value: street },
} = e.target.elements;

const supplierData = {
  name: name,
  companyId: companyId,
  ...((country || city || postalCode || street) && {
    address: {
      ...(country && { country }),
      ...(city && { city }),
      ...(postalCode && { postalCode }),
      ...(street && { street }),
    },
  }),
};
```

So this begs the question, is this just a "pick your poison" scenario? Last scenario for example, you write the code to destructure and name the properties prior to creating the object, and then within the object, the code is simpler and easier to read?

And this leads me to another question, the optimization that I am looking for, is it something worth investigating at all, or sticking to either of these scenarios is fine?

Comment: Does the `e` in question represent a submit event?

Comment: @soimon yes, its a function that handles a form submission.

Comment: @appleapple set what as undefined? I need to check if I have the values available and if I do only then assign them, this particular check is what I am talking about, is my way the "easiest" way, I am mostly concerned about the long OR that I have to make, if I have more fields, that will just get longer

Comment: miss it's a form and would default to empty string, sorry.

Comment: Can you perhaps give an example form or even a fiddle to test this with? I am close to a solution but I would like to test it in advance.

Comment: @soimon I have a form but its with custom react elements in it, its just 6 text fields and 1 submit button at the end, thats all, the first 2 are required the rest are not. Im guessing that even this will suit your needs: `const formData = {e: {target: elements: { name: {value: "somerequiredvalue"}, companyId: {value: "somerequiredvalue"}, country: {value: "nonrequiredvalue"} }}}` I hope I didnt mess up a comma.

Comment: Thanks, I have made a little mockup suitable enough for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have optimized the length of your code as far as possible with destructuring. Another way to save code is using utility functions (which I would recommend as such destructuring wizardry is prone to typos if you're doing them a lot).

The following utility functions should allow you to pick your values in a more declarative way, ensuring that no extra values are present and empty groups are omitted. Only a variant of the upper function (which is rather short and self explanatory) is necessary for every form you create.

```js
const handleAddSupplier = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const values = formToValues(e.target);
  const supplierData = {
    ...pickFrom(values, ["name", "companyId"]),
    ...optionalGroupFrom(values, "address", [
      "country",
      "city",
      "postalCode",
      "street",
    ]),
  };
  console.log(supplierData);
};


// Utility functions (you can import them from another file)

function formToValues(form) {
  const elements = form.elements;
  const values = {};
  for (const name in elements)
    if (elements[name].value) values[name] = elements[name].value;
  return values;
}

const optionalGroupFrom = (values, name, keys) => {
  const group = pickFrom(values, keys);
  const hasKeys = Object.keys(group).length !== 0;
  if (hasKeys) return {
    [name]: group
  };
  else return null;
};

const pickFrom = (values, keys) =>
  keys
  .map((key) => ({
    key,
    value: values[key]
  }))
  .filter((pair) => pair.value !== undefined)
  .reduce((map, pair) => {
  console.log( map );
    map[pair.key] = pair.value;
    return map;
  }, {});
```

```html
<form onsubmit="handleAddSupplier(event); return false;">
  <input type="text" name="name" /> name<br />
  <input type="text" name="companyId" /> companyId<br />
  <input type="text" name="country" /> country<br />
  <input type="text" name="city" /> city<br />
  <input type="text" name="postalCode" /> postalCode<br />
  <input type="text" name="street" /> street<br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can check them in loop

```js
function process(e) {
  let obj = {}
  for(let item of e.target.elements){
    if(item.value) obj[item.name]=item.value //should do proper check if it's can have valid falsy value, I leave it here for simplicity
  }
  console.log(obj)
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="process(event);return false;">
  <div>
    <label for=a>A: </label>
    <input type=text name=a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for=b>B: </label>
    <input type=text name=b>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

Comment: I like the approach, it will not directly work as I also have decorative elements within the form, but that can easily be handled within the if check, but this will make it into a plain object, I need the address items to be in a nested object under `address` and `address` should not be left as an empty object if there are no address items, it should follow the isgnature of the object that I am trying to build

Comment: @Darkbound just add it to your parent object then :)

Comment: Its all in the same form, the form gives me all values in "one level" i need to structure them in nested objects. The parent object is also made from the same values, basically, the required values are "level 1" in the object, the non-required values are "level 2" in a nested object within that same object. Just look at the examples I gave.

Comment: @Darkbound well what I'm saying is simply assign `obj` in my example to `supplierData.address` in your example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that's pretty similar in length but I think this is:

1. more readable
2. scales painlessly with new optional fields

```
const handleAddSupplier = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, companyId, country, city, postalCode, street } = e.target.elements;

    const supplierData = {
      name: formData.name.value,
      companyId: formData.companyId.value
    };

    const address = {
        country: (country || {}).value,
        city: (city || {}).value,
        postalCode: (postalCode || {}).value,
        street: (street || {}).value
    };
    Object.keys(address).forEach(key => {
        if (!address[key]) {  // Will catch null or undefined
            delete address[key];
        }
    });

    if (Object.keys(address).length) {
        supplierData.address = address;
    }
    console.log(supplierData);
  };
```